# Spatial versus Temporal locality exploitation

Tags: caching, operating-system, cpu-architecture

Which locality (spatial/ temporal) will be exploited if we put more than one word in one cache block?
Question Ref: [GATE 2011](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operating-systems-set-2/)
The answer says spatial locality. 
I have tried searching for the explanations but couldn't understand them. A detailed explanation with some example may be helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

There are two primary concepts related to [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

*Temporal locality* exists in many programs because the same memory locations are accessed multiple times.

*Spatial locality* exists because frequently if a program accesses one memory location it will also access another one that is nearby.

If a program accesses the same word in a cache line repeatedly it would exploit temporal locality because you were reusing the exact same memory location.  Storing multiple words in a cache line exploits spatial locality because if the program accesses one word in that line, the program is also likely access another word that is in the same cache line.